# WSO2 API Manager Auth error content type

Tags: json, api, authentication, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have WSO2 API Manager configured and everything seems to work fine.

The only issues bothering me is that in case of an Auth exception, the API manager always returns the response with XML content type, e.g.,

```
<ams:fault xmlns:ams="http://wso2.org/apimanager/security"><ams:code>900904</ams:code><ams:message>Access Token Inactive</ams:message><ams:description>Access failure for API: /exchange, version: 1.0 with key: 1139a466ebfd825aca953ad7259b9f45</ams:description></ams:fault>
```

In case of client communicates with my web service with JSON format, the XML response will look a little bit strange.

Is there any ideas how to make API Manager provide error response in JSON format?

Comment: Do you get this response for both XML and JSON responses?

Comment: I get the XML response all the time the API Manager I call the service and API Manager fails to authenticate or authorize the caller. It doesn't matter if I use Content-Type or Accepts header. (BTW I think carbon just removes such headers)

Comment: I am sorry but your scenario is not clear to me, what your saying is API Manager is failing to communicate with the Backend service or to authenticate your request? If your interested in XML to JSON conversion that can be done at the API Gateway.

Comment: The error messages returned by API Manager, like auth error in my initial question, are always returned in XML. Is it possible to make API Manager respond in JSON in such cases?

Comment: Can you try http://lkabimaran.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-change-authentication-failure.html ?

Answer (score 3):

This has [been addressed](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-1758) in recent versions of API Manager. Auth errors can be set to json format by adding or updating the `error_message_type` property in WSO2HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/_auth_failure_handler_.xml:

```
<property name="error_message_type" value="application/json"/>
```

I've found this also requires `JSONBuilder` and `JSONMessageFormatter` to be selected for the json content type in axis2.xml (which is the default setting).

For older versions, [this article](http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.com.ar/2013/10/how-to-convert-xml-formatted.html) explains how to manually do the same.